# Why does this imply that $S_n$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have already proven that $S_n(x) :=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k!}$ is convergent for all real $x>0$. For this I used the Monotone Convergence Theorem. Clearly this implies that $S_n(|x|)$ is convergent for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now I wish to prove that the sequence $(S_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I have arrived at the following inequality (assuming WLOG $m>n$):

$$|S_m(x) - S_n(x)|\leq|S_m(|x|) - S_n(|x|)|.$$

The lecture notes say that this implies that $(S_n(x))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence. I cannot quite see why this is the case, because I can't see how it implies there exists an $N$ such that with $m,n>N$, we have $|S_m(|x|) - S_n(|x|)|<\epsilon$. Pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

**Edit:** To clarify, I have not yet shown that $S_n(x)$ is convergent for all $x$, only $x>0$. The lecture notes show that $S_n(x)$ is convergent for all $x$, by showing that $S_n(x)$ is Cauchy, and uses an already proven result that $S_n(|x|)$ is convergent to do this. I am asking for help in understanding how to show $S_n$ is Cauchy, in particular using this scheme.

Comment: All convergent sequences are Cauchy. Cauchy is a weaker condition. Perhaps you are reading the notes awkwardly, or they are written awkwardly, or some combination thereof.

Comment: @TheCount I'm aware of this but I have not shown that $S_n(x)$ is convergent for all $x$, just for positive $x$. The lecture notes use the fact that $S_n(|x|)$ is convergent to show that $S_n(x)$ is convergent for all $x$ including $x<0$ by showing $S_n(x)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you don’t want to use that $S_n(\lvert x\rvert)$ is convergent?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Sorry if my exposition thus far has been very confusing. On the contrary, I am trying to use the fact that $S_n(|x|)$ is convergent for all $x$ to show that $S_n(x)$ is convergent for all $x$. Perhaps I am being daft and missing how this is trivial?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria I realise that I have indeed been daft. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Benjamin You‘re welcome! No problem, you are not daft:).

Comment: There's nothing like posting on MSE to help sort out the brain clutter. Glad it all has worked out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know that $S_n(\lvert x\rvert)$ converges for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Therefore, it is a Cauchy sequence especially.